# Hot to get query string from Python script (using PyISAPI on IIS)

Tags: python

I've done everything from this blog http://geographika.co.uk/setting-up-python-on-iis7.
I'm using only Python 2.6 (not Django) and want to get query string parameters in my python script.

For example, during the execution of `http://localhost/MyApp/program.py?par=test`

how to get value test in my script program.py:

```
from Http import *
def Request():
    Header("Content-type: text/html")
    Write(get_param("par"))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
from Http import *
def Request():
    Header("Content-type: text/html")
    Write(Env.QUERY_STRING)
```